# How to extend the grid lines to outside of the graph in Chart.s

Tags: javascript, chart.js, grid, axis

[image]

I can't extend the grid lines outside of the graph(canva)

[image]

In the above image represented, I want to extend the x-axis grid line to the outside of the graph(canva). If it is possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.